# Block access to my system web-application files on the server

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, security, bots

In order to make it more clear i want to understand this simple question: does changing file's extension changes its origin nature?

I mean if i change a text file (.js, .php, .html, .css) to a .exe file - does it means that crawlers / bots can't read it content?

---

ORIGINAL POST:

Abstract:
I'm trying to block access to my system web-application files on the server.

I thought of couple ways:

1. Putting restriction on  the htaccess file.
2. Implant a script (in JavaScript with/without Ajax) in order to forwarding / displaying a content to user agents that doesn't include 'bot', 'google' etc on their string.
3. Wrap my system file with alien extension like EXE etc, then use server to make a copy of it content with the proper extension (js, css, php, whatever) in order to execute it, and after the session end - delete those copies from the server.

I know how to do those 3 approaches but I wonder:

a. Which practice is the best?

b. Does this will work (i mean does one of the above will hide system files from all kind bots / crawlers out there), or is there anything else that need to be concern of?

It seems to me that the third option is the best, but I wonder: are bots able to identify if the file holds text even though it got non-text extension?

Hope that this is not out-of-scope question, but if so I would care for some good/reliable external links (or maybe other SO forum) for some guidance cause related questions here on SO are couple of years old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to completely block, but the best practice that available are :

1. Use of web application firewall, and apply rate based rule, Ex: 200 request each IP,
2. Use captcha sdk in web application.
3. This is best, consider using honeyPot, which means add some hidden URL in you pages like:`example.com/adminArea/dashboard`, there is no chance that a legit user will hit these url, so definitely a bot or crawler or hacker will hit this address, which will block IP in real time.

Edit: 
[Link1](https://www.hostpapa.in/blog/security/how-to-eliminate-bots-from-your-website/) : Bots are 2 types, good & bad, simply goodBots do not crawl urls from "robots.txt" and other but bad bots do not care of "robots.txt". So you can block good-bots to crawl with your solutions but not bad-bots.

[Link2](https://resources.distilnetworks.com/all-blog-posts/9-recommendations-to-prevent-bad-bots-on-your-website) : Captcha, Monitoring, & 3rd party vendor like cloudFlare are solution that everyone recommend. you can add my tricky "honey-pot" solution in this list :)

Thanks,
jaikey sarraf

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I edit a little the question in order to narrow the subject.

Comment: No, changing extension is not a solution, crawler are advance, they not depended on extension.

Comment: Thank you. So i understand that if a crawler wants to scrap my files no meta tag, no httaccess, and no different extension would help me to hide my files. Is that correct? if so, please edit your answer with reputable sources and i consider to award the bounty to you sir.

Comment: Thanks, i edited as per requirement, i hope this help you.. 
i also like to share something interesting with you, that how "BOTs" are smarted now days. https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/

Comment: Thank you. Your links helps me alot!

Comment: nice to hear that. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Using robots.txt

For disallowing the bots you can use robots.txt file on your server. Most of the legal and friendly crawler and bots first read the robots.txt file and start crawling on website on the urls which are allowed and ignore which are discouraged.

Meta tag also has property to tell bot to halt it's operation.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /~joe/
```

### Using .htaccess

And second you can use htaccess to rewrite your actual file in such a way that not  nobody can tell easily that the request is going to the exact file which is requested or you can block permanently if you'd like to.

Something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (crawler|bot) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

### Using captcha

As suggested by other users captcha is also a good way to filter out bots.

References:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha

https://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: Thank you for that, that robotstxt link you provide was one of me resource too.